# Creating Activities dynamically with Sqlite Table for every activity?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am designing an App which will allow user to create as much activities as he wants and create sqlite table for every activity to store data. Every activity will contain same design/UI as other but will store data for different client in its related sqlite table.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Why he need to create new activities if they have same Design. You can create one activity and circulate data for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An activity is the UI so if they are the same then there is no need to create multiple activities all you need to do is pass different data (probably just a single value or two) to a single activity.

Likewise, there is no very likely no need to have a table per user, rather just have a column that indicates the client in a single table. Noting that the each table adds a minimum of 1k (4k by default since SQLite 3.12.0). You would probably only need to split data, for speed, if there were 10 of 1000's of rows.

Of course it's then simply a matter of extracting the appropriate data.

As an example. Here's a a two table (activites and values) that allows values to be saved  on an activity basis (noting that activities is probably not the best term).

#### DBHelper.java

This includes the structure/schema used to build the database and the tables within. It also has some basic methods to add activities, values for activities and to retrieve the list of activities and a value from the stored values on a per activity basis.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "activity.db";

    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TBNAME_ACTIVITY = "_activity";
    public static final String COL_ACTIVITY_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_ACTIVITY_NAME = "_activity_name";
    public static final String COL_ACTIVITY_USERID = "_activity_userid";
    public static final String UNQCNSTRNT_ACTIVITY_USERID_NAME = "_activity_userid_name_unique";

    public static final String TBNAME_VALUE_STORE = "_value_store";
    public static final String COL_VALUE_STORE_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_VALUE_STORE_ACTIVITY = "_value_store_activity";
    public static final String COL_VALUE_STORE_NAME = "_value_store_name";
    public static final String COL_VALUE_STORE_TYPE = "_value_store_type";
    public static final String COL_VALUE_STORE_ORDER = "_value_store_order";
    public static final String COL_VALUE_STORE_VALUE = "_value_store_value";
    public static final String UNQCNSTRNT_VALUESTORE_ACTIVITY_NAME_ORDER = "_value_store_activity_name_order";

    public static final int VALUETYPE_INTEGER = 1;
    public static final int VALUETYPE_STRING = 2;

    private static final String CRTSQL_START = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ";
    private static final String CRTSQL_IDCOL_TYPE = " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crt_activity_table_sql = CRTSQL_START +
                TBNAME_ACTIVITY + "(" +
                COL_ACTIVITY_ID + CRTSQL_IDCOL_TYPE +
                COL_ACTIVITY_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                COL_ACTIVITY_USERID + " TEXT " +
                ", CONSTRAINT " +
                UNQCNSTRNT_ACTIVITY_USERID_NAME +

                " UNIQUE (" +
                COL_ACTIVITY_USERID +
                "," +
                COL_ACTIVITY_NAME +
                "))";
        String crt_value_store_table_sql = CRTSQL_START +
                TBNAME_VALUE_STORE + "(" +
                COL_VALUE_STORE_ID + CRTSQL_IDCOL_TYPE +
                COL_VALUE_STORE_ACTIVITY + " INTEGER, " +
                COL_VALUE_STORE_NAME + " TEXT," +
                COL_VALUE_STORE_TYPE + " INTEGER, " +
                COL_VALUE_STORE_ORDER + " INTEGER, " +
                COL_VALUE_STORE_VALUE + " unspecified " +
                ", CONSTRAINT " +
                UNQCNSTRNT_VALUESTORE_ACTIVITY_NAME_ORDER +
                " UNIQUE (" +
                COL_VALUE_STORE_ACTIVITY +
                "," +
                COL_VALUE_STORE_NAME +
                "," +
                COL_VALUE_STORE_ORDER +
                "))";
        db.execSQL(crt_activity_table_sql);
        db.execSQL(crt_value_store_table_sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    }

    public Cursor getActivities() {
        return mDB.query(TBNAME_ACTIVITY,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public  String getValueString(String value_name, long activity_id) {
        String rv = "no value?? for activity " + String.valueOf(activity_id) + " value_name of " + value_name;
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBNAME_VALUE_STORE,
                new String[]{COL_VALUE_STORE_VALUE},
                COL_VALUE_STORE_ACTIVITY + "=? AND " +
                        COL_VALUE_STORE_NAME + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(activity_id),value_name},
                null,null,COL_VALUE_STORE_ORDER
        );
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_VALUE_STORE_VALUE));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public long addActivity(String activity_name, long userid ) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_ACTIVITY_NAME,activity_name);
        cv.put(COL_ACTIVITY_USERID,userid);
        return mDB.insert(TBNAME_ACTIVITY,null,cv);
    }

    public long addStringValueStore(String name, long order, String value, long owning_activity ) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_VALUE_STORE_VALUE,value);
        return addValueStore(name,order,cv,owning_activity, VALUETYPE_STRING);
    }

    public long addIntegerValueStore(String name, long order, long value, long owning_activity) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_VALUE_STORE_VALUE,value);
        return addValueStore(name,order,cv,owning_activity, VALUETYPE_INTEGER);

    }

    private long addValueStore(String name, long order, ContentValues cv, long owningactivity, int type) {
        cv.put(COL_VALUE_STORE_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COL_VALUE_STORE_ORDER,order);
        cv.put(COL_VALUE_STORE_ACTIVITY,owningactivity);
        cv.put(COL_VALUE_STORE_TYPE,type);
        return  mDB.insert(TBNAME_VALUE_STORE,null,cv);
    }
}
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String INTENTKEY_ACTIVITYID = "iextra_actviityid";

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    Cursor mCsr;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    ListView mActivityList;
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;
        mActivityList = this.findViewById(R.id.activity_list);
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        bldDemoDBActivities();
        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getActivities();
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mCsr,
                new String[]{DBHelper.COL_ACTIVITY_NAME},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0
        );
        mActivityList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mActivityList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,BaseActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(INTENTKEY_ACTIVITYID,l);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    private void bldDemoDBActivities() {
        long current_activity;
        current_activity = mDBHlpr.addActivity("Activity 1",0);
        mDBHlpr.addStringValueStore("mystring",0,"Rumplestiltskin",current_activity);
        if (current_activity > 0) {
            mDBHlpr.addIntegerValueStore("A number", 0, 42, current_activity);
            mDBHlpr.addIntegerValueStore("intarray", 0, 33, current_activity);
            mDBHlpr.addIntegerValueStore("intarray", 1, 44, current_activity);
            mDBHlpr.addIntegerValueStore("intarray", 2, 55, current_activity);
        }

        current_activity = mDBHlpr.addActivity("Activity 2",0);
        if (current_activity > 0) {
            mDBHlpr.addStringValueStore("mystring", 0, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", current_activity);
        }
    }
}
```

#### BaseActivity.java

This is the invoked activity with different data passed (just 1 value the owning/initiating activity's id, this being sufficient to get the values from the value store table) :-

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    TextView mMyString;
    long mActivityId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
        mMyString = this.findViewById(R.id.mystring);
        mActivityId = this.getIntent().getLongExtra(MainActivity.INTENTKEY_ACTIVITYID,-1);
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        if (mActivityId > 0) {
            mMyString.setText(mDBHlpr.getValueString("mystring", mActivityId));
        } else {
            mMyString.setText("Oooops no valid activity passed.");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Resultant App :-

**Initial**

[image]

**Click Activity 1**

[image]

**Click Activity 2**

[image]